# Организация тем с использованием sass в Yii2

Tags: yii2, sass, themes

Думаю как сделать темы для сайта на `Yii2`. Создается на основе шаблона `advanced`.

Сейчас в каталоге `web`, куда направлен сервер лежит такая структура:

```
_dev/
    sass/
        _global.scss
        _vars.scss
        site.scss
css/
    site.css
```

Из `_dev/sass/*` все просто компилится в `css/*`.

Как бы я сделал без `sass`
Положил бы рядом с `web`, или прямо в `web` каталог `themes` с примерно такой структурой:

```
themes/
    classic/
        css/
            mod1/
                mod.css
            mod2/
                mod.css
            theme.css
```

Таким образом файлами `theme.css` и `mod.css` переопределял бы существующие стили, или добавлял бы новые. И в итоге на странице бы подключались 3 `css` файлика:

```
main.css - основные стили
theme.css - изменения для темы
mod.css - изменения для модификации темы
```

Но с `sass` хотелось бы использовать фишку с переменными. К примеру, в `mod.scss` я бы хранил только переопределенные переменные с цветами и картинками.

Первый вариант: я делаю структуру как описал для `css`, и пытался бы описать `sass` так, чтобы чтобы в итоге получился `css` файлик с переопределенными стилями.

Второй вариант: я делаю описанную выше структуру для `css`, делаю файлики `mod.sass` с переопределенными переменными, делаю файлик `combine.sass`, где описываю нужные инклуды и в итоге на сайт подключается только один mod.css, куда будет скомпилено все, что подключено в mod.scss. Подход не нравится, т.к. в каждой теме будет куча дублированного css (хотя я с ним не буду работать, ведь я правлю только sass файлы...)

Третий вариант: В `Yii2` есть встроенные препроцессоры для sass, less и тд. и возможность у `AssetBundle` указывать `sourcePath`, чтобы фреймворк сам скопировал файлики в доступное из веба место. И используя это попытаться описать логику тем в AssetBundle (а не через конфиг `themes`) так, чтобы нужные файлы компилились только для активной темы. (Но я пока не знаю как это сделать)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как, на ваш взгляд оптимальнее было бы сделать задуманное? Или может быть кто-то уже реализовывал подобное? Спасибо за любую идею.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вобщем сделал следующим образом.
Тему поделил на такие части:

1. Маска. Переопределяет сетку сайта. Может быть полностью новый дизайн.
2. Модификации. Переопределяет отдельные части сайта. Виджеты, компоненты, списки или что-то еще.
3. Стили. Содержит только переменные с цветами, шрифтами, картинками и тд.
4. Темы. Содержит sass файл, содержит только инклуды вышеперечисленных файлов. Компилится в соответствующее место в папке web

   themes
       v1
           mask
               sass
               views
           mods
               footer.v2
               leftsidebar
           styles
               default
               darkblue
           themes
               default
                   sass
               darkblue
                   sass
       v2
           mask
           mods
           styles
           themes

Comment: Почему-то не работает форматирование кода... Помогите, пожалуйста